# Slash in the ActionName attribute for MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, url

Is it possible to have a slash in the ActionName attribute in ASP MVC?

e.g. I would like a paths

```
MyController/MyAction1
MyController/MyAction2/A
MyController/MyAction2/B
MyController/MyAction3
```

The reason for this is it mimics the navigation a user would use. But if I try to add the following to `MyController` it doesn't work.

```
[ActionName("MyAction2/A")]
public ActionResults A() {...}
```

Obviously without the attribute it wouldn't work either.

I've tried changing my `RouteConfig.cs` to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyController",
    url: "MyController/MyAction2/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index" }
);
```

But this affects all MyController paths. How can I get either a slash in the action name, or have the route config 'override' only come in to play when the action is MyAction2?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done in MVC 5 using `Route` annotation.[Enable MVC 5 Routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Example from the blog :

```
[Route(“books/lang/{lang=en}”)]
    public ActionResult ViewByLanguage(string lang)
    {
        return View(“OneBook”, GetBooksByLanguage(lang));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did notice you could do this in MVC5, unfortunately I'm using MVC4